# Using innerHtml with button tag is not appear in angular

Tags: angular

my component class has string like this:

```
  text: string = "I am <button type='button' class='btn btn-link p-0 hashtag'
        (click)='searchHashtag(innerHTML)'>#happy</button> because I have 
  <button type='button' class='btn btn-link p-0 mention'>@sarah</button>";
```

and my html template has:

```
 <div class="container">
   <p [innerHtml] = "text"></p>
 </div>
```

The output I get is:

```
I am  because I have
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular HTML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding)

Answer (score 0):

You need to capitalize the **HTML** part of **innerHtml**.

```html
<div class="container">
   <p [innerHTML]="text"></p>
 </div>
```